# RMarkdown ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘yaml’

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

I updated R to the latest version "R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)". I am using macOS Mojave.

Now, when I am trying to knit the code in the Markdown, I get an error. I figured this is because I don't have an updated version of the "yaml" package. However, when I am trying to update the "yaml" package, I get the following errors:

```
installing the source package ‘yaml’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/yaml_2.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 89447 bytes (87 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 87 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Chicago'
* installing *source* package ‘yaml’ ...
** package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘yaml’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/yaml’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/yaml’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘yaml’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_r/cgv1gmqx1vzgv25k1k805lyw0000gn/T/RtmpagnKIL/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: R 33.3 is **not** the latest version but several years old. Try updating to the current version 3.6.0.

Comment: You are totally right! I had the latest version of the RStudio, but not R. This worked, thank you a lot!